# Keep getting gibberish output when trying to print an array in C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, reverse, c-strings

I am trying to write a program that reverses words in a sentence, the code is able to do that but also prints gibberish in between. (see below code for sample)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_VALUE 50
int main(){
    char c[MAX_VALUE],
        b[MAX_VALUE];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while ((c[i] = getchar()) != '\n'){
        i++;
    }
    
    for(i = MAX_VALUE; i >= 0; i--){
        if (c[i] == ' '){
            for(j = i+1; j < MAX_VALUE; j++){
                if (c[j] != ' '){
                    printf("%c", c[j]);
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    
    while (c[i] != ' '){
        printf("%c", c[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Loop goes backwards when it detects a space it prints the word until it finds another space then goes backwards again from where it left off last

The input and output expected:

input: `test a is this`

output: `this is a test`

What I get:

input: `test a is this`

output:

```
this
`����l�,+�D     �=� is a test
```

Answer (score 0):

This for loop

```
while ((c[i] = getchar()) != '\n'){
    i++;
}
```

can write outside the array `c` and store the new line character `'\n'` in the array.

And this output consisting from two lines

```
this
`����l�,+�D     �=� is a test
```

demonstrates that the new line character was stored in the array.

Also you forgot to append the entered sequence of characters with the zero terminating character `'\0'` to form a string.

You could write the while loop the following way

```
int ch;

while ( i < MAX_VALUE - 1 && ( ch = getchar() ) != '\n' && ch != EOF ){
    c[i++] = ch;
}
c[i] = '\0';
```

Or if you want store the entered sequence without the terminating zero character `'\0'` then the loop can look like

```
int ch;

while ( i < MAX_VALUE && ( ch = getchar() ) != '\n' && ch != EOF ){
    c[i++] = ch;
}
```

In this case the variable `i` will contain the number of entered symbols in the array and you should use its value instead of the value `MAX_VALUE` in the following loops.

This outer for loop

```
 for(i = MAX_VALUE; i >= 0; i--){
```

is incorrect because the user can enter a sequence of symbols that contains less than `MAX_VALUE` symbols. You should either use standard string function `strlen` (if you appended the sequence with the terminating zero character `'\0'`) to determine the length of the string stored in the array or the value of the variable `i` as mentioned above that denotes the number of entered symbols.

And it is not enough to check this condition

```
if (c[i] == ' '){
```

because the leading spaces can be absent in the entered string. So you need to check also whether `i` is equal to `0`. Otherwise the  output can be incorrect if the sequence contains for example only one word.

The inner for loop

```
for(j = i+1; j < MAX_VALUE; j++){
```

again is incorrect by the same reason of using `MAX_VALUE` in the condition.

Pay attention to that the array `b`

```
char c[MAX_VALUE],
    b[MAX_VALUE];
```

is not used in your program.

Using your approach I can suggest the following solution to output words of a string in the reverse order shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *s = "test  a  is  this";

    for( size_t i = strlen( s ); i != 0; )
    {
        while ( i != 0 && isblank( ( unsigned char )s[i-1]) )
        {
            putchar( s[--i] ); 
        }

        size_t j = i;

        while ( j != 0 && !isblank( ( unsigned char )s[j-1]) )
        {
            --j;
        }

        if ( j != i )
        {
            size_t last = i;
            i = j;
            while ( j != last )
            {
                putchar( s[j++] );
            }
        }
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
this  is  a  test
```

Answer (score 0):

The code uses two arrays and two 'counters', and fiddles around with individual characters one-at-a-time. It's easy to get lost and use an *upper bound* that is outside the array size.

Simplify! This "reversal" is an excellent example of when **recursion** should be the *go-to* method of solving the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void output( char *p ) {
    if( (p = strtok( p, " " )) == NULL ) return;
    output( NULL );
    printf( "%s ", p );
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the dogs";

    output( str );

    return 0;
}
```

```
dogs the over jumps fox brown quick The
```

Some purists may want an entire buffer to be assembled before printing. This resulting string includes an invisible SP at the end that could be lopped off if desired.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *revWords( char *dst, char *p ) {
    if( (p = strtok( p, " " )) == NULL ) return NULL;
    revWords( dst, NULL );
    return strcat( strcat( dst, p ), " " );
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the dogs";
    char buf[sizeof str + 1 + 1] = { 0 }; // important to initialise

    puts( revWords( buf, str ) );

    return 0;
}
```

For an alternative, here's a version without recursion. It requires, like above, a *mutable* buffer holding the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "   The quick brown fox jumps over the dogs    ";
    int i = 0;

    // note: 1 string buffer, 1 index variable

    for( i = 0; str[i]; i++ ) ; // loop

    while( i >= 0 ) {
        while( i >= 0 && !isalnum( str[ i ] ) ) str[i--] = '\0';
        while( i >= 0 &&  isalnum( str[ i ] ) ) i--;
        printf( "%s ", str + i + 1 );
    }
    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```